# Google Place NearbySearch for Lodging with Price

Tags: google-places-api, google-maps-sdk-ios

I want hotel/lodging list within a particular price range.
I tried with maxprice and minprice filter but its returning empty results.

Here is my google places API :
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=18.563102,73.785511&type=lodging&rankby=distance&minprice=0&maxprice=5&key=your_key

But its not returning any result.

Is there API to fetch 'lodging' list within required price range? or get two star hotels?

Please let me know your solutions.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that when you are looking for hotels/lodging places, there is no 'price_level' attatched to these places like if you were to search for a restaurant using the google places api.